# Implementation of generic interface with specific type in Java

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following generic interface:

```
interface Petlover<T>{
    void train(T somePet);
}
```

I understand that it's possible to provide generic implementations to generic interfaces (e.g., `class MalePetLover<T> implements Petlover<T>`). But I am having trouble implementing the interface for a specific type only:

```
class Dogperson implements Petlover<T> {
    int age;

    void train(String someDog){...};
}
```

The compilation error is `train(String) in Dogperson cannot implement train(T) in Petlover`. What would be a right way to handle this?

Comment: `implements PetLover<String>`? You should clarify what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: The `String` is intended to be the name of a dog. I tried `Petlover <String>` to no avail (please see Eran's answer below) - the same error is output by the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you expect `train` to accept a `String`, your class should implement `Petlover<String>`:

```
class Dogperson implements Petlover<String> {
    int age;

    public void train(String someDog) {...};
}
```

or perhaps the `train()` method of `Dogperson` should accept a `Dog` argument, and then the class would implement `Petlover<Dog>`.

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error after changing `T` to `String` as you suggest: `error: train(String) in Dogperson cannot implement train(T) in Petlover`. Yes, it would be better to use a `Dog` object, but I just kept it as `String` for simplicity.

Comment: @flow2k It passed compilation for me. You just have to add `public` access modifier to the `train()` method.

Comment: Ah - okay. I missed that in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Side note: You should follow the Java naming conventions.

Comment: @LewBloch Do you mean CamelCase?

Comment: I mean the Java naming conventions. Not all names are in camel case, and there's far more to naming conventions than just case. Why don't you look up the conventions, @flow2k?

Answer (score 3):

The subclass that extends a generics class has to conform to the type that it specifies in its own declaration.

You declare : `class Dogperson implements Petlover<T> {`, so the `train()` method has to have this signature :   `void train(T someDog){...};`

If you want to have this signature in the subclass:

```
void train(String someDog){...};
```

you have to declare a subclass that implements `PetLover` by specifying the `String` class as parameterized type :

```
class Dogperson implements Petlover<String> {
     public void train(String someDog){...};
}
```

You can specify any parameter as `T` derives from Object in the interface.
For example, if you want to have a Dog as type used in the subclass, you could write it :

```
class Dogperson implements Petlover<Dog> {
     public void train(Dog dog){...};
}
```

For example, if you want to have a Cat, you could write it :

```
class Catperson implements Petlover<Cat> {
     public void train(Cat cat){...};
}
```

Comment: Like Eran mentioned in the other answer, the `train` methods in the Dogperson and Catperson classes need to be `public`.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt True. Interface methods has to be public. We would have seen it before.