# Implement interface with two generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I've got a task as a part of my homework and I can not get over it.
[image]

The code of the transformer interface is the following:

```
public interface Transformer<FROM, TO> {
    TO transform(FROM value);
}
```

The code of the `PersonSubscriberTransformer` class looks like this so far:

```
public class PersonSubscriberTransformer<FROM, TO> implements Transformer {
    private Predicate<Person> predicate;
    public PersonSubscriberTransformer(Predicate<Person> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }
    @Override
    public Object transform(Object value) {
        return null;
    }
  }
```

The paramether of the transform method should be `List<Person>` and it should return a `List<Subscriber>`. As I'm changing the paramether I got an error saying I should pull the method to the Transformer interface.

What would be the solution to implement this method in the correct way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementation of generic interface with specific type in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964199/implementation-of-generic-interface-with-specific-type-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the intended signature of `transform`, `FROM` should be `List<Person>` and `TO` should be `List<Subscriber>`. The class itself should not be generic.

```java
public class PersonSubscriberTransformer implements Transformer<List<Person>, List<Subscriber>> {
    // constructor...
    
    @Override
    public List<Subscriber> transform(List<Person> persons) {
        // complete this method...
        return null;
    }
}
```